# Problem assign float to an embed class within the Linked-list libary

Tags: c++, library, class, float

I have successfully implemented some code which uses a linked-list.  Everything is working, except assigning a value to a float within the embeded class.  When I run the code below, I get the expected behavior, a flashing LED for 10 secs then LED turns continuously ON, and I also get the debug messages I expect.  However, when I comment the marked line to assign a value to the float, it still compiles, but the LED does not flash as expected and I get complete rubbish from debug.  I am using codebender on Chrome, and I have tried Firefox (both given same results).

Main Sketch https://codebender.cc/sketch:175995

Example of library working https://codebender.cc/sketch:176008

Can anyone help?

```
typedef void(*GF)(void);

#include "LinkedList.h"

class CsC {
    public:
        float PerS;
        GF FunctionToCall;
};

LinkedList<CsC*> TaskList = LinkedList<CsC*>();

void LEDON()
{
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
}
void after(float interval, String intervalDescription, GF func);

void after(float interval, String intervalDescription, GF func)
{
    float multi = 1;
    if(intervalDescription == "mins") multi *= 60;
    float delayMS = multi * interval;
    CsC *c;
    //Error if either of these lines uncommented
    //c->PerS=10000;
    //c->PerS=delayMS;
    c->FunctionToCall=func;
    TaskList.add(c);
    Serial.print(".");
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Serial.println("Start write task list");

    after(35,"secs",LEDON);

    Serial.println("Done");
    Serial.println("Start prog");
}
void loop()
{
    Serial.print("List=");
    Serial.print(TaskList.size());
    while(TaskList.size()>0){
        CsC *c=TaskList.shift();
        long timeout=millis()+10000;
        //long timeout=millis()+((long)(c->PerS*1000.0));
        while(millis()<timeout){
            //To indicate it is running, and to save time, I have used a delay here
            digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
            delay(250);
            digitalWrite(13,LOW);
            delay(250);
        }
        c->FunctionToCall();
    }
    Serial.print(".");
    Serial.println("complete");
    while(1){}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered allocating memory for `c`?

Comment: I thought in c++ i did not have to allocate memory.  If I did allocate memory beforehand, how would I do it?

Comment: With the `new` operator. And you deallocate it with the `delete` operator.

Comment: My mistake, I will try tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible error is a memory leak as you did not allocate the memory to the class
Try

```
CsC *c=new CsC();
```